# Create an administation subpage containing posts in a certain category

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, add-submenu-page

I have a website with 3 post-types. My boss wants to create an additional post-type containing only posts from a certain category.

For example, I want all the posts under the category "important" to be arranged in a subpage/post-type automatically (tabled preferably). I need this page so that it can be reordered and filtered easily.

Is there a way to do it in wordpress? Help please. My wordpress version is 4.8

Thank-you in advance

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here on a similar question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/401940?noredirect=1 that discusses a plugin I did that might start to meet your needs.

The plugin is called Multisite Post Reader, and can be found here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/401940?noredirect=1

Comments about additional features can be posted in the plugin support page.

If the plugin is not exactly what you need, you can always dig into the plugin code and tweak it for your needs. That's how I built the plugin - using techniques found in various locations here and on the googles.